# getMonth() returning the following day for some reason

Tags: javascript

I'm retrieving a list of dates from my database and getting the month from those dates. 
When I get month for this date it returns 0 for January.

```
var date = new Date('2015-12-31T22:57:12.000Z').getMonth();
```

When I get month for a similar date it returns 11 for December.

```
var date2 = new Date('2015-12-31T12:24:29.000Z').getMonth();
```

Comment: getMonth returns months from `0` and ends at `11`. You have to add one with the result if you want from `1-12`

Comment: 3 answers, several upvotes, but that's not what OP is asking. OP is asking why the same Dec date can be parsed as Dec or Jan, depending on the hour (this is probably just a timezone issue). On top of that, **if** this was indeed just a zero-based issue, the question should be closed as a duplicate, not answered **again**. To the OP: try [UTC](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/UTC) and tell us what happens.

Comment: Which time zone are you operating?? your date string converted to date Object using your local browser machine timezone. @GerardoFurtado I agree with you

Comment: @Reez0 look at my answer below which i explained why its happening as you are operating from GMT+2 Johannesburg

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will give the right result:

```
var date = new Date('2015-12-31T22:57:12.000Z').getUTCMonth();
```

If your timezone is GMT+02, then you can try like this also:

```
var date = new Date('2015-12-31T22:57:12.000+0200').getMonth();
```

Answer (score 1):

As you want to why this both Dec **string** dates returning different month? This is the answer:

From your profile i could see your are from south Africa which is **GMT+2** timezone.

**First date string** : **2015-12-31T22:57:12.000Z**, which is 31 Dec and **22.57** hours mid night. While creating date object out of string date at client browser side, It's takes your local timezone into account. Its **GMT + 2**.

Thus, it adds 2 hours: 2015-12-31T**22:57**:12.000Z + 2 hours => **22.57** hours shift to next day after addition of 2 hours(22.57 +2 => next day 00.57), which would be January month morning 0.57 hours. So it returns 0 (January) Month.

**While second** : **2015-12-31T12:24:29.000Z** which is **12:24** hours which shifts to 14.24 in same day after addition on 2 hours as above. So you are still in 31 Dec. hence you receive December for this.

Answer (score -1):

The months in javascript are numbered from `0` to `11`, days from `1` to `31`